# Image classification Using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, data-science, image-classification

this is the code where I was working on Image Classification using Pytorch and I'm not able to get the  accuracy right.
the accuracy is exceeding 100 ,can anyone help me to find the error.

```
     def trained_model(criterion, optimizer, epochs=5):

      epoch_loss = 0.0
      epoch_accuracy = 0
      running_loss = 0
      running_accuracy = 0
      total = 0

      for epoch in range(epochs):
        print('epoch : {}/{}'.format(epoch+1, epochs))

        for images, labels in train_loader:
          images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

          optimizer.zero_grad()

          outputs = model(images)
          loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

          _, predictions = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)

          loss.backward()
          optimizer.step()

          running_loss += loss.item()

          running_accuracy += torch.sum(predictions == labels.data)
          


        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataset)
        epoch_accuracy = running_accuracy / len(train_dataset)

        print('Loss:{:.4f} , Accuracy : {:.4f} '.format(epoch_loss, epoch_accuracy))

      return model
```

Comment: Add code as formatted text, not as an image please

Comment: Are your labels one-hot-encodings or indices?

Comment: @couka Thank you for the suggestion, I didn't know as I was new to this.

Comment: @Ivan Thnak You! It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html)  to get the class predictions from your model output, instead of `torch.max`.

Assuming you are working with indices as labels. Something like the following will get you the average accuracy of the current batch:

```
>>> outputs = torch.rand(16, 5)

>>> pred = torch.argmax(outputs, axis=0)
tensor([14, 11, 13, 15,  7])

>>> labels = torch.tensor([14, 6, 13, 5, 8])

>>> accuracy = (pred == labels).float().mean()
tensor(0.4000)
```